# Validation failed: <something> is not included in the list (only in tests)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

How that might be?
in orders model:

```
validates :pay_type_id, inclusion: PayType.ids
```

in tests:

```
patch :update, id: @order, order: { address: @order.address, email: @order.email, name: @order.name, pay_type_id: PayType.ids.first }
assert_equal [], PayType.ids
```

tests result:

```
1) Error:
OrdersControllerTest#test_should_create_order:
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Pay type is not included in the list
    app/controllers/orders_controller.rb:41:in `block in create'
    app/controllers/orders_controller.rb:40:in `create'
    test/controllers/orders_controller_test.rb:36:in `block (2 levels) in <class:OrdersControllerTest>'
    test/controllers/orders_controller_test.rb:35:in `block in <class:OrdersControllerTest>' 

2) Failure:
OrdersControllerTest#test_should_deny_update_if_not_logged_in [/home/eugenes/Dropbox/work/depot/test/controllers/orders_controller_test.rb:85]:
Expected: []
  Actual: [298486374, 980190962]
```

In development environment all ok.
What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have any `PayTypes`?

Comment: I don't know if the inclusion can be a Proc or lambda, but I suspect the issue is that your validation code runs at class init time.  So when the test framework starts up, there are no PayType objects.  And then inclusion (maybe) is "[]'.  Instead you might want to use a proc so that the validation always runs knowing the latest set of PayType.

Comment: Yes, of course, I have 2 pay types.

Comment: I edited question, now you can see that pay types exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably do something like

`validates_inclusion_of :pay_type_id, :in => lambda { |_| PayType.pluck(:id) }`

At least this way, every time the validator runs, you'll make a fresh query to the db and get the latest set of PayType ids.

ps. The dummy param `_` is included because of a bug - for followup, check out  https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/13689.

Comment: After some investigation i found that it works with proc: validates_inclusion_of :pay_type_id, in: proc { PayType.ids }